# Cannot open server requested by the login. The login failed. No extended error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-connection, arcgis

I am trying to connect an ArcGIS Pro user to an Azure SQL database.

The following values were specified in the Database Connection window:

Database Platform: SQL Server

Instance: servername.database.windows.net

Authentication: Azure Active Directory password

Username: username@orgname.org

Password: adifferentpassword

This produced the error in the post title. The server that it highlights is the organization, such as 'orgname.org'.

I had the user specify the username username@orgname.org@servername, but the value is too long for the input field.

The user was created with the command `CREATE USER [username@orgname.org] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;`

I already verified that it is not a permissions nor firewall problem because the user can connect to the database in Microsoft Excel and return a result set with a SQL query.

I had the user try a SQL username and password with Authentication: SQL Authentication and it produced the error that the server principal does not have access to the master database.

Comment: Could you please where did you try to connect SQL server like in SSMS or in portal?

Answer (score 0):

I created user and granted permissions to the user with below code.

```
CREATE login [loginname@microsoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER 

CREATE USER [username] for login [loginname@microsoft.com]
Alter role db_owner add member [username];
```

when I try to connect my sql server to SSMS I faced the same issue.

[image]

AFAIK when connecting with SSMS it takes the master database as default database, but the user is created in database named db, so I go to options tab and browse for and enter the db name where created the user manually without browsing. Because browsing also not possible with the user.

[image]

In that process it connected successfully.

[image]

Otherwise create user in master database in grant permissions regarding to our requirements then it is possible to connect without any error.

Comment: The user is not trying to connect via SSMS. The user is trying to connect via ArcGIS Pro. That is where the issue is encountered.

Comment: Do you create user via ArcGIS Pro or Azure portal?

Comment: The user was created in SSMS. The user can connect to the database and return a result set using Microsoft Excel. The user cannot connect to the database using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Did you select the required database other wise it will connect to master database by default where user was not created?

Comment: The option to select the required database is only available after the data source/database server is entered. The error is produced before the database can be selected.

Comment: Once check with SSMS, is it giving the same error?